# How to autoload php extensions

Tags: php

I am using php -S to serve server for my scripts.
It use custom function, so I have to load php extension. I can do it with -dextension.so parameter but is there another way?

My question is there any other way how to do it?

I tried to edit php.ini and added extension=extension.so into it but it does not worked...

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

You can create extension.ini in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d with one line:
extension=extension.so

and it will work...